# What does "deserve a good kicking" mean?

Tags: slang

I encountered this expression in a passage and did not understand.
can anyone help explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**kicking**   [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kicking)

noun

> ```
> An assault in which the victim is kicked repeatedly.
> ‘they gave him a **good kicking**’
> ```

As in:

> ‘A few good kickings later I quickly forgot that idea!’

and

It might seem deserved, but giving him a good kicking really isn't the answer.

Comment: Like a beating, but with the feet, not the fists. Also British slang for a particularly severe verbal attack or criticism, often in a work situation or politics.

Comment: "Ideally the Trump administration would stop treating Europeans as free-riders on American power who deserve a good kicking. " In this piece, who deserve a  good kicking then and why according to the author?